# Java regex mid-string matching

Tags: java, regex

I have a dictionary file containing lines
ns*.abc.com
ns*.xyz.com
I want to match patterns such as ns15.abc.com, nsABC.abc.com with the dictionary file and return true. 
E.g. ns15.abc.com is match while ns16.ABC.abc.com is not a match. 
Thanks in advance

```
public class ValidateDemo {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
    List<String> input = new ArrayList<String>();  

    input.add("ns14.abc.com");
    for (String str : input) {
        if (str.matches("ns*.abc.com")) {
            System.out.println("Match: " + str);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have already tried? It will help us know what you are trying to do.

Comment: public class ValidateDemo {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  List<String> input = new ArrayList<String>();
  input.add("ns14.abc.com");


  for (String str : input) {
   if (str.matches("ns*.abc.com")) {
    System.out.println("Match: " + str);
   }
  }
 }
}

Comment: Please don't post it in a comment. Edit it into your question.

Comment: Sorry, It was accidental. I have updated the post.

Comment: Your string doesn't use regex syntax. You can find out how to write a regex at http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In each entry from the dictionary, replace asterisk by `"[^\.]*"` and dot by `"\."` - there's your pattern for each individual entry:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^" + dictEntry.replaceAll(".", "\\.").replaceAll("*", "[^\\.]*") + "$");
```

Or you can also join all dictionary entries with "|" to have single pattern matching them all.

Comment: Note: if you use Java 6, instead of escaping the dots, you can surround your literal text with `\Q`...`\E`.

Comment: @fge or more generally, use `Pattern.quote`, which is designed for precisely this task, to turn a string into a regex that would match that string literally.